# Tomcat 7: "Cannot locate Java Home"

Tags: tomcat, environment-variables, arch-linux, java

Arch Linux. Servlet apparently had compatibility problems with openjdk so I uninstalled it and installed the plain jdk/jre from AUR.

```
# /etc/rc.d/tomcat7 restart
:: Stopping tomcat7 daemon [FAIL] 
:: Starting tomcat7 daemon [BUSY]
Cannot locate Java Home
```

Added `export TOMCAT_JAVA_HOME=/opt/java` to `/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh` (and equivalent under `jdk.csh`), rebooted. `echo $JAVA_HOME` and `echo $TOMCAT_JAVA_HOME` both return `/opt/java`, but still no dice. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue following this page: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/24126

Basically you have to add  these lines in your /etc/rc.d/tomcat7 file, below the line ". /etc/conf.d/${daemon_name}"

```
# The JAVA_HOME of the JVM for Tomcat to use

if [ -x /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk ]; then
TOMCAT_JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
elif [ -x /opt/java/ ]; then
TOMCAT_JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/
fi

# Tomcat additional commandline options
CATALINA_OPTS=
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try doing :

```
sudo env
```

root mustn't be allowed to see environment the way "we" do.

The [Sudoers Manual](http://www.gratisoft.us/sudo/sudoers.man.html) has this to say...

> Since environment variables can influence program behavior, sudoers provides a means to restrict which variables from the user's environment are inherited by the command to be run.

... and ...

> By default, the env_reset option is enabled. This causes commands to be executed with a minimal environment containing the TERM, PATH, HOME, MAIL, SHELL, LOGNAME, USER, USERNAME and SUDO_ variables in addition to variables from the invoking process permitted by the env_check and env_keep options.

My solution was :

```
# Create a sudoers extension file and authorize passing JAVA_HOME, M2_HOME, etc into new environment
cd ~/
rm -f neededBy*
echo 'Defaults env_keep+="JAVA_HOME M2_HOME CATALINA_HOME TOMCAT_USER"' > neededByTomCat
chmod 0440 neededByTomCat
sudo cp neededByTomCat /etc/sudoers.d/
```

I hope this helps,

Hasan

Comment: I was already root; no `sudo`ing involved. Tried your solution anyway though; didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get anything by typing "javac" in the console?  That will tell you if you have JDK installed rather than just JRE.  Also, type the command "which java" to see where your java is linked to.   I never use ArchLinux, but on Ubuntu and Mint, they use the alternatives link system to link the default Java installation... in that case I use a tool called "galternatives" to configure Oracle Java after I install it.

I don't think Arch Linux uses the alternatives system like Ubuntu does, but it seems like adding java to the PATH environment variable, in your .bashrc , would be the way to go, rather than unnecessarily editing the JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_HOME env variables in the tomcat script (since the script should be able to auto-determine those based on the java binaries location).

Comment: `javac` exists, yeah. As I said I installed the JDK from AUR (community repo). `which java` is `/opt/java/bin/java`. No alternatives system on Arch. Anyway, Java is already in my `PATH`. Haven't edited any existing variables; only added a new one (`TOMCAT_JAVA_HOME`).

Comment: @Hugh Guiney -  what happens when you try robregonm's answer?  Also, when you set your var do you also export it?   This shouldn't be this hard of an issue and you have given us limited information.  Can you possibly post your start script or is it too long?

Answer (score 0):

Open `catalina.sh` and add the following lines before the first code lines (but ofc below the shebang)

```
JAVA_HOME=/opt/java
JRE_HOME=/opt/java/jre
```

Adjust the path to fit your needs. No need to manipulate any PATH or persistent variable for Tomcat to work properly.

Comment: Tried this. Didn't work.